# Returning a gif image from a method

Tags: java, image, gif

I am creating an application in java which will be the part of an external application. My application contains a viewport which shows some polygons and stuff like that. The external application needs to get the image of the viewport in gif format. For that it calls a method in an interface (implemented by my application) and my application returns the image. The external application needs to store the image in database (or something related to it which I dont need to worry about).

My question is:- What should be the data container type of the image when my application send it to the external application? I mean what should be the return type of the method?
Currently my gif encoder class returns a byte array. Is there any other 'better' option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A byte array could be appropriate if you expect the GIFs to be small, but you might consider using an `OutputStream` so you can stream bits more efficiently.

Even if today you just return a fully-populated `ByteArrayOutputStream`, this would allow you to change your implementation in future without affecting cilent code.

Comment: the gif image will be of size 150 X 150 pixels.

Comment: That's nice and small.  A byte array is fine.

Answer (score 2):

A more intuitive return type might be java.awt.Image.

Here are some examples:
http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=java+gif+image&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code

Comment: but the java.awt.Image object will be platform and format independent. The external application requires a gif image.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'application' is actually calling a Java method then it should understand Java return types and you should return java.awt.image.

If you are doing this through some kind of remote procedure that can't understand Java types I would return a byte array and let the receiving app decode it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create two methods:

1. First method creates the image and returns a `java.awt.Image`. Here you can put the drawing part of your method.
2. The second method creates a gif representation of the `java.awt.Image` as requested by the external application. It should return `OutputStream` as already suggested.